# rails merit gem does nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

I'm using the merit gem for badges/points, and it does nothing in the app. In the console it works, but in the app it doesn't.

in merit.rb:

```
# Use this hook to configure merit parameters
Merit.setup do |config|
  # Check rules on each request or in background
  config.checks_on_each_request = true

  # Define ORM. Could be :active_record (default) and :mongo_mapper and :mongoid
  config.orm = :active_record

  #Define :user_model_name. This model will be used to grand badge if no :to option is given. Default is "User".
  config.user_model_name = "User"

  # Define :current_user_method. Similar to previous option. It will be used to retrieve :user_model_name object if no :to option is given. Default is "current_#{user_model_name.downcase}".
  config.current_user_method = "current_user"
end

# Create application badges (uses https://github.com/norman/ambry)
Badge.create!({
 :id => 1,
 :name => 'just-registered'
})

Badge.create!({
  :id => 2,
  :name => 'voter',
})

Badge.create!({
  :id => 3,
  :name => 'liker-on-steroids'
})
```

In point_rules.rb:

```
module Merit


class PointRules
include Merit::PointRulesMethods

def initialize
  # score 10, :on => 'users#update' do
  #   user.name.present?
  # end
  #
  # score 15, :on => 'reviews#create', :to => [:reviewer, :reviewed]
  #
  # score 20, :on => [
  #   'comments#create',
  #   'photos#create'
  # ]

  score 10, :on => 'users#update' do |user|
    user.nickname.present?
  end

  score 20, :on => 'pictures#create', :to => :user

  score 5, :on => 'pictures#vote_up', :to => :user do |picture|
    picture.vote_up
  end

  score 5, :on => 'pictures#vote_against', :to => user do |picture|
    picture.vote_against
  end
end
end
end
```

Let's take the 20 points on pictures#create:

```
def create
    @picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])
    @picture.user_id = current_user.id
    @picture.fame = false
    if @picture.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Picture saved."
    else
      redirect_to root_path, error: "Could not save picture."
    end
  end
```

routes:

```
resources :pictures do
    member do
      post :vote_up
      post :vote_against
      post :unvote
    end
  end
```

but it's not just this. Nothing works, it literally doesn't respond - whatever I do, it gives the user no points or badges.

I am using OmniAuth (facebook) to register the users

Comment: I'm really scratching my head with this, it makes no sense...

Comment: When you say "it does nothing in the app", what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: it's supposed to add points/add a badge, yet it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post the code that is supposed to trigger the points?

Comment: Added in original post.

Comment: It still won't work for an unknown reason

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Look at this](https://github.com/tute/merit/wiki/How-to-grant-badges-on-user-registration-using-Devise), i think that can give you a way!

good luck!

Comment: Link goes to add new wiki page form